# Add button to white background NSPopover, but the button has shadow area

Tags: objective-c

all:

I have one customized NSPopover, and I set it's background color into white. Then I add one Button without border into the viewcontroller, and put the viewcontroller into the NSPopover. The question is that, there will be shadow area for the button in this NSPopover, could someone have any ideas about this?
The issus is also exist for Label.
The customized  NSPopover code is as follow:

https://github.com/shergin/NSPopover-MISSINGBackgroundView

and the result is:[The final result of adding button to NSPopover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69hd4.png)

Comment: if (!backgroundView.superview) {
        NSView *contentView = self.contentViewController.view;
        NSView *frameView = [contentView superview];
        frameView.wantsLayer = YES;
        backgroundView.frame = NSInsetRect(frameView.frame, 1.f, 1.f);
        backgroundView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
        [frameView addSubview:backgroundView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:contentView];
    }

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You could improve your question by putting the code in the question itself, instead of a comment, and format it as code (with the {} button). Also, be more clear in what you want to achieve and what is going wrong. I don't see a shadow for the button in the screen shot, for example. What did you expect, and what is not happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug. 
Set the appearance property of the textfield to NSAppearanceNameAqua.